# Voting without paying fees

Tags: erc-20, signature, fees, voting, governance

I'm Alex and currently exploring the governance smart contracts.

I would like to create an ERC20 token where holders are able to vote/sign multiple propositions made by the owners account.
Is there a way to do so where the voter can sign/vote without paying any fees?

I think this should be possible, but can't really find any concrete implementation.

Have an amazing day!

Answer (score 1):

At one point you will have to spend the gas. Take a look at Gnosis Safe. They offer a way to sign the transaction and when all the signatures are made you can make the call. This is a big process that users are unaware of but there is a backend/api handling all that. They even have a network of node to maintain the process.

So yes you can do this. But you will need a way to store your signature and verify them. Now you will be able to sign a transaction but it does not mean that the transaction is valid.

Example I could sign a transaction for which I don't have the amount and send you the signed transaction and that would be valid. But once on chain it would fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it made things more clear! I'm making an ERC20 token on BSC that includes some tokenomics like RFI and voting. I used the ERC20Votes library from Openzeppelin. I do now know that holders can vote with my token but it is not clear how and where. When an ERC20 token implemented the Votes library, it does need another contract right? Like a proposition contract? Could you clarify that part for me? :)

Comment: Let's assume I'm building an UI where people who posseses a certain coin can vote for proposals, created by me, without paying anything (=by signing). How should I implement this? (With an API I assume). Thanks for your reply, really appreciate it! Trying to figure this out since some time now xd